# Google Api - Key with file:// protocol

Tags: file, api, google-maps, cordova, dictionary

I have a little problem with the google api loading script.
I try to load the map api with this script tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places&language=en-US?key=xxx"></script>
```

The problem that I have is that google keep telling me :

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. This
>   site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided. If
>   you are the owner of this application, you can learn more about
>   registering URLs here:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/auth#registering_authorized_urls

I have tries to set the allowed referers to "*", and to not specify any referer at all, but always get the same error message.

I think that it's because I'm in a phonegap (cordova) app and that the page where the script tag stand is loaded by file:// protocol...

Some of you have already solved this issue ?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the map api key with file:// protocol. Google checks the web site domain, but file:// protocol does not have it, so you can skip it.

By the way, [phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/) brings native Google Maps view into your Cordova app. 
It's better performance (although less functions than Google Maps JS API v3).
Just for your information.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "You don't need to use the map api key with file:// protocol."  If I don't Google refuses to load the map, it tells me there was an error and if I click on more info it says it's because there was no API key specified.  (Earlier it would load the map but put a gray translucent foreground over it with "Developer Mode" text all over)

Comment: Check "when I answered". Situation in 2016 and 2018 are different.